# How does shared_from_this in std::bind work where object does not exist?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, bind, shared-ptr

Is that code safe?

```
class C : public std::enable_shared_from_this<C> {
    void start() {
             boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_), 
             std::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
             _1, _2));
    };
    // ...
};

class D {
    void start()
    {
         std::shared_ptr<C> cptr = std::make_shared<C>(); // (1)
         cptr->start();
    } // (2)
};
```

If the message is long, the `async_write` operation can take a long time.

There is only one `shared_ptr` pointing to the `C` object at point (1). `start()` is called, `start()` finishes and at (2) the variable `cptr` goes out of scope and is destroyed.

When `async_write` has finished the writing operation, the callback is called; this causes a crash because `shared_from_this()` tries to make a `shared_ptr` to a non-existent object.

Is this description of what would happen correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you are not right.

The call to `shared_from_this()` happens before `start` returns. A copy of the resulting `shared_ptr` is held by the result of `bind`.

So when you reach (2) only one of the two references to the object has gone, and it remains alive

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't want to write new question. I'd like to also know what if in code above handler wouldn't be a method (so there wasn't `shared_from_this` or `this` in bind) - handler would be a function. And in D::start I create normal variable: `C c`. Is it ok if c is destroyed before async_write finishes? Is callback called always ok in this case?

Comment: It depends. If the handler accesses `c` in any way (e.g. via some pointer or reference) then you have a problem. If not it's fine. (Another option would be to pass a copy of `c` to the handler; whether that works depends on the details of your handler.)